# Find the stationary points of $f(x) = 2x_1^3 -3x_1^2 -6x_1x_2(x_1-x_2-1)$ and see which of them are maxima or minima

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, optimization, maxima-minima

> Find the stationary points of $$f(x) = 2x_1^3 -3x_1^2
>  -6x_1x_2(x_1-x_2-1)$$ Which os these points are minimizers, maximizers, local or global?

$$f(x) = 2x_1^3-3x_1^2-6x_1x_2(x_1-x_2-1)$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} = 6x_1^2 -6x_1-12x_1x_2+6x_2^2+6x_2$$

$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1^2} = 12x_1-12x_2-6$$

$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_2\partial x_1} = -12x_1+12x_2+6$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} = -6x_1^2+12x_1x_2+6x_1$$

$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_2^2} = 12x_1$$

You can verify the hessian matrix [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=hessian%20matrix%202x%5E3-3x%5E2-6xy(x-y-1))

I must first see which points make the first derivatives $0$. I know that $(0,0)$ and $(-1,-1)$ do it, so let's find the others:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} =0 \implies -6x_1^2+12x_1x_2+6x_1 = 0\implies x_2 = \frac{x_1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}, x_1\neq 0$$

I don't even need to do $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}$ because if $x_2 = \frac{x_1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}$ is not satisfied then I don't need to find the points that give $0$ in the first coordinate of $\nabla f$, because the second already doesn't give $0$. Ok, so for $x_1\neq 0, x_2 = \frac{x_1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}$.

If $x_1=0$ we have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} = 0$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} = 6x_2^2 +6x_2$ whch is $0$ at $x_2=0$ only, so the points where $x_1\neq 0$ are not our concern.

I think now we must solve find which poins of the form $(x_1,\frac{x_1}{2}-\frac{1}{2})$ satisfy $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} = 0$:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}((x_1,\frac{x_1}{2}-\frac{1}{2})) = 6x_1^2 -6x_1-12x_1(\frac{x_1}{2}-\frac{1}{2})+6(\frac{x_1}{2}-\frac{1}{2})^2+6(\frac{x_1}{2}-\frac{1}{2})\implies x_1 = \pm 1$$
When $x=-1, x_2 = x_2=-1$. When $x=1, x_2=0$

So all the points are:

$$(0,0), (-1,-1),(1,0)$$

$$H(0,0) = 0\\ [x \ y]H(-1,-1)[x \ y]^T = -6x^2+12xy-12y^2\mbox{ not always positive or 0}\\ [x \ y]H(1,0)[x \ y]^T = 12y^2 -12xy+6x^2 \mbox{ not always positive or 0}$$

The $3$ critical points I found doesn't satisfy the necessary condition to be minima or maxima. So I think I should analyze the neighborhood of these points analytically. However the function is too ugly for me to do that. I think I should have found conclusive answers on my hessian. Can you see anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you haven't quite well looked at the case $x_1=0$. In that case, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}=0$ for every $x_2$, but $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}$ becomes
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(0,x_2)=6x_2^2+6x_2,$$
which is zero both for $x_2=0$ and $x_2=-1$. So you missed the critical point $(0,-1)$.

As for the Hessian matrix I got
$$H(0,0)=\left(\begin{matrix}-6&6\\6&0\\\end{matrix}\right),$$
$$H(-1,-1)=\left(\begin{matrix}-6&6\\6&-12\\\end{matrix}\right),$$
$$H(1,0)=\left(\begin{matrix}6&-6\\-6&12\\\end{matrix}\right),$$
$$H(0,-1)=\left(\begin{matrix}6&-6\\-6&0\\\end{matrix}\right).$$

The first one and the last one have negative determinant, and that means they represent undefined quadratic forms. This assures that the corresponding critical points are not extrema, but saddle points indeed.

The second and the third one have positive determinant, which implies they are extrema; the second one represents a negative definite quadratic form and the third one a positive definite quadratic form. This implies that at $(-1,-1)$ and $(1,0)$ there are a relative maximum and a relative minimum, respectively.

Comment: How can you affirm things about the hessian matrices by the determinant? Is there a rule that says matrices positive determinant are positive definite or negative? If so, do you know a sketch of the proof?

Comment: That holds for $2\times 2$ matrices. A particular case which can give some insight is that of diagonal matrices. If both entries in the diagonal (that is, in fact, both eigenvalues) are positive, or both are negative, the determinant will be positive (it is the product of them). In one case the matrix will be positive definite, and in the other case it will be negative definite. But if they both have different sign, they will yield a negative determinant. The determinant can only be zero if at least one of the elements in the diagonal is zero.

Comment: The general proof makes use of the fact that every symmetric matrix can be diagonalized and so you can make a relation between eigenvalues and determinant of the matrix and the sign of the first element (the principal $1\times 1$ submatrix.)

Comment: What's the criterion you have to analyse the definiteness of a symmetric matrix?

Comment: I was analyzing $xHx$ and seeing if they were always positive or always negative. In these cases, I can say that the points are extrema. In the case of $xHx$ being not always positive or not always negative, I can't say that they are extrema, but I don't recall this implying that they are saddle points. If the hessian is not always def. positive or def. negative then the point is automatically saddle?

Comment: How can I say that $xH(-1,-1)x$ and $xH(1,0)x$ are always positive? $xH(-1,-1)x$ is giving me $-(12y^2-12xy+6x^2)$. How can this be always negative? It is $0$ for $(0,0)$ at least. And for the rest of the points I don't know how to factor this.

Comment: If there is at least one $x$ such that $x^THx$ is negative and at least one such that it is positive, then this means is not a maximum nor a minimum (because the matrix is indefinite). Whether it is a saddle point depends on the definition you have for them, but for most usual definitions I would say that the answer is that it is a saddle indeed.

Comment: All quadratic forms are $0$ when evaluated at $(0,0)$. That vector is out of the question. The matrix is positive (negative) definite if for every $x\neq 0$ you have $x^T H x>0 (<0)$.

Comment: $-(12y^2-12xy+6x^2)=-6(2y^2-2xy+x^2)=-6\big((x-y)^2+y^2\big).$

Comment: And this is obviously $\le 0$, and can only be zero when $y=0$ and $x-y=0$, that is for $(x,y)=(0,0)$.